# How to use Ruby/Nokogiri to Strip <tr> and <td> tags not enclosed in <table> tag?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm dealing with some badly formed HTML where table elements aren't enclosed in a table tag, such as the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns main-content">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><img src="../img/H006265.jpg"></td>
    </tr><tr valign="top">
    <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to get rid of the junk tags and end up with something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns main-content">
    <img src="../img/H006265.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

There are legit tables elsewhere in the document, so I'm not able to just strip  and  tags altogether, only those not enclosed in a  tag.

I've tried having Nokogiri parse it, thinking it would clean up the incorrect HTML, to no avail:

```
Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(badly_formed_html_string)
```

Comment: have you tried using XML instead ? At least to clean it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Uri's code for helping me find a good answer, his was close but this did the trick for me of stripping those tags only when not enclosed in a  tag:

```
def strip_tag_if_not_in_parent(doc, tag, parent)
  doc.css(tag).each do |element|
    if (element.parent.name != parent)
      new_element = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(element.inner_html)
      element.replace new_element
    end
  end

  doc
end

doc = strip_tag_if_not_in_parent(doc, 'tr', 'table')
doc = strip_tag_if_not_in_parent(doc, 'td', 'tr')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parsed fragment to clean your HTML:

```
frag = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(badly_formed_html_string)
frag.css('tr').each do |tr|
  tr.add_previous_sibling tr.children
  tr.remove
end
frag.css('td').each do |td|
  td.add_previous_sibling td.children
  td.remove
end
puts frag.to_s
# <div class="row">
#   <div class="large-12 columns main-content">
#     <img src="../img/H006265.jpg">
#      
#     </div>
# </div>
```

Comment: Close, but I don't want to remove ALL <tr> and <td> tags, only those not enclosed by a <table> tag. But very helpful and I voted it up.